# Why does psycopg2.execute_values split the execution into multiple pages?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a large update statement and found psycopg2 execute_values to the rescue. But after some funny bugs and further investigation I stumbled across pagesize. And found out that I needed to execute it in one page to avoid deadlocks. But I could really explain why the psycopg2 splitet the executetion into different pages in the first place. I hope you can help clarify this.

Comment: Because executing everything in a single statement increases memory load (as all the data has to be processed by postgres at once), which is usually unnecessary, so the goal is to reach a sweet spot between "not too much data" and "not too many batches" (as each batch is a network roundtrip). If your code deadlocks because of this, I feel like your code is broken.

Comment: The code might be broken its complicated.

Comment: If pagesize is to decrease memory load only it still does not make sence to me since python have the data preloaded. If there is no other reason I would I would have set the default option to run without pagesize. Sure that there are no other reasons?

Comment: "python have the data preloaded" postgres needs its own copy. "If there is no other reason I would I would have set the default option to run without pagesize." no, this has no reason to be the general default, normal queries don't break just because you're doing more than one sequentially.

Comment: Either way [they're arbitrary values arbitrarily selected by the maintainer](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/797#issuecomment-433436864)